# Is there a way to print a snapshot of a job that's in the background to standard output?

Tags: bash, stdout, job-control

If I have a job that's running/paused in the background, is there a way of printing a snapshot of its activity to standard output?

Comment: Like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323956/how-to-redirect-output-of-an-already-running-process

Comment: Is the output saved in any temporary file? if yes, then you can do a `tail -f <file_name>`

Comment: I think this answers my question @pLumo, thanks

Comment: @pLumo Yes! Thanks again